# How can I position views over a NSTextView such that they have no fixed position, but a sort of gravity to a point?

Tags: macos, appkit

So I have an NSTextView with text in it. Some of the parts of the text have a NSTextAttachment.Key so I can find their position in the NSTextContainer. I'm adding notes/annotations to the text right now just by hard coding the frame of the annotation to be under the given part of the text. This fails miserably when two annotations are close to each other(they then overlap), or when an annotation's text position is near an edge of the NSTextView(it then gets clipped and cut off).

What I would really like is to set a rule like, this view(the annotation), likes to be close to this given point, but is flexible. This view does not want to overlap other views or go beyond the bounds of the parent view.

The other rule which may be harder is, this view does not want to cover the NSTextView text. Since that text is not a view itself, one solution may be, since I'll know the font size, and the line height, I could calculate that if say the lines of text are at Y positions 100, 200, 300, etc. Then the annotation could only have Y positions of 75, 125, 175, 225, etc.

Some other notes:

- This NSTextView is not editable. It is display only and updates based on changes to another NSTextView, so these positions won't need to be dynamic such that a user is adding text in realtime, rather at fixed intervals the editable textview's content is read, the annotations queried from the backend, and then the text is written into the read-only textview's NSTextStorage, and the annotation NSViews are added to the read-only NSTextView.
- MacOS/AppKit only. No UIKit

Here is a diagram of the sort of thing I'm aiming to achieve, and was wondering what is the right tool in the AppKit toolbox to try and achieve this? Can something like AutoLayout work with these types of flexible constraints? Or is my only option to rollout something custom that does all of these calculations, and then gives a fixed NSRect to each annotation's NSView?

[image: Here is an example of the type of layout I'm talking about]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it out of the box but there are couple of things you could look into.

- [Exclusion paths](https://Exclusion%20paths) will help you with not covering the actual text view. Whenever you create the note view, just add an exclusion path which could perhaps cover the whole line (meaning a rect of `0, y, fullContainerWidth, lineHeight`).
- Using `NSPopover` instead of normal `NSView`s. They can pop out of the actual window and won't be clipped outside the screen. There is no way to avoid overlapping with them, though.
- There are some popover subclasses (such as [SFBPopovers](https://github.com/sbooth/SFBPopovers/)) which allow more flexible positioning.

In either case, you will need to do some maths to avoid overlapping. The best way to do this in your case is probably to enumerate the attributes/text attachments. From there, you can figure out which lines will need to have notes displayed, and calculate in advance how much they will take space, and if you'll have to display them both below and above the line.

Note that you will need to do this as you go along, because the layout and
attribute range rects will change as you add exclusions.

If you decide to go with `NSView`s, you might want to look into creating a specific container `NSView` subclass for displaying the notes for a single line. It's much easier to handle positioning the notes in local coordinate space, and to figure out how much space they take. You can then display this specific view on top of your `NSTextView` where needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I was dreading having to write the logic myself to find the best fit, with so much variation in the density of notes, and length of notes. I think I'll default to having them all along the bottom row, and if there's overlap try pulling the longest note in the overlapped section up to the top row until it's down to only minor overlaps, then figure out the ideal left/right shifting. The idea of having a row view makes sense. Will exclusion paths distort the text? Right now I'm using line spacing, as I was worried ex. paths might make the regular text non-linear.

Comment: Exclusion paths are completely avoided, and don't distort text. Here's a good article about using them (refers to iOS but applies to macOS as well):
https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/getting-to-know-textkit/